# Listbox and observablecollection in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, observablecollection

I have listBox that show invoice items :

```
        <ListBox x:Name="lbInvoice" ItemsSource="{Binding ocItemsinInvoice}"  Margin="10,27,0,143" Width="412" HorizontalAlignment="Left" BorderBrush="{x:Null}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ToggleButton x:Name="btnInvoiceItem" Checked="btnInvoiceItem_Checked" Style="{StaticResource InvoiceBG}" TabIndex="{Binding ItemsinInvoiceID}" Padding="20,0,0,0" FontSize="12" Width="408" Height="35" Foreground="#FFcfcfcf" IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}, Mode=FindAncestor}}" BorderThickness="1,0.5">
                        <ToggleButton.BorderBrush>
                            <SolidColorBrush Color="#FF5B616F" Opacity="0.7"/>
                        </ToggleButton.BorderBrush>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Item.ItemName}" Width="200"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding SalePrice}" Width="50"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Quantity,NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True}" Width="50"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Total}" Width="50"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </ToggleButton>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

The problem is when I change the quantity value in code behind (click event for example)

```
ItemsinInvoice _lbi = (ItemsinInvoice)lbInvoice.SelectedItem;
_lbi.Quantity = 99; //for example
```

on screen the value of quantity in the list dose not change, did I miss any thing.

Thanks

Comment: How does `ItemsinInvoice.Quantity` property look like? Do you implement [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx) interface?

Comment: How can I implement INotifyPropertyChanged interface?

Comment: This link will help you - [How to implement INPC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743695(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

If you want your changes to ViewModel to be automatically reflected in the view then your class needs to implement [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and you need to raise `PropertyChanged` event each time property has changed value:

```
public class ItemsinInvoice : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    #region INotifyPropertyChanged

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    #endregion

    private int _quantity;

    public int Quantity
    {
        get { return _quantity; }
        set
        {
            if (_quantity != value)
            {
                _quantity = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Quantity");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

> I do not know how to use this code, can you explane it?

It's very simple code but will try to break it down for you. First you need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface

```
public class ItemsinInvoice : INotifyPropertyChanged
```

This interface has one `PropertyChanged` event that you need to publish in your class

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
```

then you you write helper method to safely raise this event for specified property name:

```
private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
{
   ...
}
```

and that's `INotifyPropertyChanged` implemented. Now you need to call above `OnPropertyChanged(...)` method with property name each time property changed value so in this example for `public int Quantity { ... }` your call looks like this `OnPropertyChanged("Quantity")` and you have to remember that it is case sensitive so property name must match exactly.
By implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface and raising `PropertyChanged` event for property name you tell binding that property with this name changed its value and all related bindings require refresh.

Comment: I do not know how to use this code, can you explane it? sorry but I'm new with INotifyPropertyChanged.